# Which camera for lane detection

Tags: video, camera, computer-vision

I am working on a lane detection algorithm based on deep learning.
At the end I want to test the algorithm with a Jetson TX2 in a car.
For that I need a good camera which I can install inside the car(windshield).
It should be able to:

- livestream the captured video to the Jetson TX2 board in realtime (via USB or Bluetooth?)
- very good video quality

Are there better solutions beside dashcams?
I am looking for a very good camera, which is not too big. Price does not matter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try USB Cameras from leopard imaging and e-con systems. Both companies are official partner of NVIDIA.

https://www.e-consystems.com/See3CAM-USB-3-Camera.asp

https://leopardimaging.com/product-category/usb_3-0_camera/